# How to get list of published docker images from GCP registry programmatically

Tags: java, docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-registry

I'm trying to find some API (for example java, but could be some other) how to get published docker image names / tags from google cloud platform registry. I found how to do this using gcloud console commands:

```
gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/[GCP_REPOSITORY_NAME]
```

And it basically gave what I want, but it is console and I need this data get programmatically on back-end side. Any ideas guys? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is no REST API for the Google Container Registry product but you can [use the Registry name as an URL](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/overview#registry_names_as_urls) and run an [HTTP request](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#listing-image-tags) within your Java code against it:

```
curl -u "oauth2accesstoken:yourAccessToken" https://gcr.io/v2/yourProject/yourImage/tags/list
```

You can get the `accessToken` with the command `gcloud auth print-access-token`. The recommend approach is that it belongs to a serviceAccount.

Although I am not sure if the [Docker Registry HTTP API V2](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/) is fully compatible with Google Container Registry, this specific method has worked for me.