# Getting a list of Containers from GCR

Tags: reactjs, curl, fetch, google-container-registry

I can currently use `curl -u "oauth2accesstoken:token-value" https://gcr.io/v2/_catalog`  to fetch the list of containers in my registry, is there a way to do this through a web app?

I have tried using `fetch('https://us.gcr.io/v2/_catalog',{method:'GET', headers:header }).then(res=>console.log(res)).catch(err=>console.log(err));` but keep getting 405 CORS error. Am I doing someting wrong or is this just impossible?

My header is `header.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got it working by setting up a proxy server using ExpressJs which made a HTTP call to the us.gcr.io. Then, I made a call from my react app to the express app and was able to get the data :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that what you want is to get a list of the containers from GCR.

In order to do that, you can use the gcloud command "gcloud container images list"

You can find more details on its documentation reference [1].

As per the description:

"The container images list command of gcloud lists metadata about existing container images in a specified repository. Repositories must be hosted by the Google Container Registry."

On the other hand, I have found this other link [2] that may serve you.

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/images/list

[2] [How to get list of published docker images from GCP registry programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55059636/how-to-get-list-of-published-docker-images-from-gcp-registry-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks for the response. By programmatically I meant through a web app. I have edited my question. These links give the CLI commands which already work as I have written in my question.